# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL no ph_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to install locally a website created by someone else.
However, I can't manage to connect the database with the actual website. On Firefox, I get the following error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "147.---.---.---", user "myuser", database "mydb" SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "147.---.---.---", user "myuser", database "mydb" SSL off
```

(The address "147.---.---.---" is my personnal IP address.)

I've tried to find a solution on the internet, and after loads of attempts to correct my problem, I have the following pg_hba.conf file:

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
host    all     all     127.0.0.1/0     md5
local   all             postgres                                trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       md5
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     postgres                                trust
host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Of course, after every update made on pg_hba.conf, I restarted postgresql with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Does anyone have an idea on why this doesn't work? Why do I always have the same error? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `pg_ctl reload` is enough. If you enable `log_connections` in `postgresql.conf`, what messages to you see in the log?

Comment: CEST LOG:  connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=49960
CEST LOG:  connection authorized: user=myuser database=mydb

Comment: That's a localhost connection. If you see no entry that corrsponds to the error message in your question, that means that you are connecting to a different PostgreSQL server.

Comment: That's wierd, it corresponds to the exact moment where I refreshed my page, plus the user and database are those used in the configuration file of my website.

Comment: The database is on a different host that the application server, right? Any connection pooler like `pg_bouncer` or other proxy?

Comment: Everything is on the same host, my localhost. It's all on the same physical machine.

Comment: I thought that thanks to this line: host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       md5 I'd accept any type of connection...

Comment: Correct. Since you don't see a FATAL error message in the log, your connection to the local database was successful. The error message you receive must come from a different database.

Comment: But I only have one installation of postgresql...?

Comment: I've done a "locate pg_hba.conf" and I only have this file once...

Comment: Problem solved... I had modified the configuration files of the website but some paths were hard-coded in other files...